# Database Mail Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-mail

I am getting a strange error randomly when i try to send emails using database mail using SQL Server.

The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure.Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found).

and whenever i restart SQL Server it starts working.
Is there any clue or trouble shooting which i can do to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a DNS issue.
confirm by trying to resolve the smtp server name from a windows command prompt whenever you start getting errors again. (before you reboot the server)

Comment: thanks for your reply could you please do let me know it in more detail how can i resolve SMTP server name from a windows command.

Comment: in a windows command prompt type nslookup, followed by enter. then type the smtp server name exactly as you entered it in your database mail configuration and then hit enter. The DNS server should now reply with an ip adres.

Comment: how to promt it? using ping?